# Ler valores de uma estrutura Json usando Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json, symfony

Estou tentando ler os dados que são recebidos via `php` e preciso ler esses valores separadamente. O retorno é um objeto `json`, quando eu mostro no console usando o comando `console.log(data)` e aparece a seguinte estrutura:

```
{"clientes":[
   {"idEntidade":"314","nmEntidade":"3D Inform\u00e1tica Ltda"}, 
   {"idEntidade":"439","nmEntidade":"Academia BigBone Fitness"}, 
   {"idEntidade":"308","nmEntidade":"Academia de Ginastica Forca e Saude Ltda - ME"},
   {"idEntidade":"371","nmEntidade":"Academia Simetria"}
]}
```

Porém se eu tento acessar uma posição com o comando `console.log(data[0]['nmEntidade'])` por exemplo, a resposta é `undefined`.

Código Jquery

```
    $.getJSON('../caminho/do/json', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data[0]['nmEntidade']);
    });
```

Método PHP que retorna os dados.(Estou utilizando o framework [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) )

```
public function filtraClienteAction()
{        
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $connection = $em->getConnection();
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT idEntidade, nmEntidade FROM entidades ORDER BY nmEntidade");
    $statement->execute();
    $clientes = $statement->fetchAll();

    $response = new JsonResponse(json_encode(array(
        'clientes' => $clientes
    )));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return $response;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai conseguir acessar assim:

```
console.log(data['clientes'][0]['nmEntidade']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Vc está acessando errado, o correto é informar o objeto antes e a sua posição depois que no caso é 0 , tem que acessar o objeto que é **cliente** antes.

```
$.getJSON('teste.json', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.clientes[0]['nmEntidade']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver criando a seguinte estrutura:

```
    $.getJSON('../caminho/do/json', function (data) {
        var clientes = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(clientes['clientes'][0]['nmEntidade']);
    });
```

Comment: Aceite uma das respostas Diego para fechar a questão no site.